# Python 2.7 cannot import PyQt4

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, python-2.7

I've upgraded to Python 2.7 from Python 2.6 on Ubuntu Maverick Meerkat (10.10) and I'm unable to import PyQt4.

```
austin@gerald:~$ python2.7
Python 2.7.0+ (r27:82500, Sep 15 2010, 18:04:55) 
[GCC 4.4.5] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import PyQt4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named PyQt4
```

I installed both Python 2.7 (python2.7) and PyQt4 (python-qt4) from the Ubuntu repositories. I installed PyQt a while back, but I installed Python 2.7 recently.

If I try Python 2.6 (since it's shipped with Ubuntu, the command is simply *python*), it works perfectly. Watch:

```
austin@gerald:~$ python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Sep 15 2010, 15:52:39) 
[GCC 4.4.5] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import PyQt4
```

I know what the problem is: the PyQt4 modules are accessible by Python 2.6 but not 2.7. My question is, how do I get Python 2.7 to find the PyQt4 module(s)? Help!

*Note: sorry if this belongs in Super User, I was just programming when I encountered this problem.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under Ubuntu system, you could install it via apt-get

```
apt-get install python-qt4
```

Comment: Marking this as the answer because even on the oldest supported Ubuntu release (12.04 LTS atm), the `python` package is now version 2.7. Thanks!

Comment: Note, if you're using a virtualenv, you'll need to remove the file `no-global-site-packages.txt` from `<env>/lib/python2.7` in order to import PyQt4 from your global Python site-packages.

Answer (score 9):

As PyQt is not using setup.py it cannot be installed using pip or easy_install

Here you have a tutorial showing how to build and install PyQt for python2.7:

http://problemssol.blogspot.com/2010/12/compile-and-install-pyqt4-for-python27.html

**Update:**
For Ubuntu 12.04+ just use apt-get:

```
apt-get install python-qt4
```

Answer (score 4):

OSX 10.8.2 tested:

```
sudo pip install SIP
```

got IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/pip-build/SIP/setup.py'

It's ok then:

```
cd /tmp/pip-build/SIP
sudo python configure.py
make
sudo make install
```

download PyQt from: http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/PyQt4/PyQt-4.9.6/PyQt-mac-gpl-4.9.6.tar.gz

unzip it.

```
cd PyQt-mac-gpl-4.9.6
sudo python configure.py
make
```

it will take a while, after make then:

```
sudo make install
```

Enjoy it :)

Comment: Running make gives me 'error: unable to open output file 'main.o': 'Error opening output file 'main.o'''

Answer (score 2):

You can download any version of PyQt4 here for any version of Python but since you asked for python 2.7, Here is the link for the download for python 2.7:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/PyQt4/PyQt-4.11.4/

Answer (score 1):

You should install PyQt4 in the Python 2.7 environment. To do this run

```
easy_install2.7 PyQt4
```

If easy_install is not installed you will need to first download and install it by running

```
python2.7 setup.py install
```

Comment: excuse me but i want to do one remark , why not pip ? haven't you heard ,"easy_install is dead long live to pip" :)

Comment: That didn't work. When I run "easy_install-2.7 PyQt4" it just says "Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/PyQt4/
Couldn't find index page for 'PyQt4' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/
No local packages or download links found for PyQt4
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('PyQt4')" :( How do I use pip?

Answer (score 1):

Please install SIP module first,this is python and c/c++ lib tools, and PyQt4 lib