# PyQt4 install problems on Ubuntu

Tags: python, pyqt4

I have PyQt4 installed and running with Python2.7 on Ubuntu, this works fine. Now I want to use PyQt4 with Python3.

- I have been trying for several hours to install PyQt4 with Python3.4.
- I installed sip-4.16.4. This worked fine.
- I then tried installing PyQt-x11-gpl-4.11.3.

I get a message:

> The Qt Designer plugin was disabled because a dynamic Python library could not be found.

I then ran `make` and had an error that `Python.h` could not be found. I then created a sym link as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17698877/fatal-error-while-compiling-pyqt5-python-h-does-not-exist)

I then ran make again I got an error:

> fatal error abstractaudiooutput.h No such file or directory and compilation was terminated.

I tried a virtual environment and installed pyhton3.4 from scratch. Things progressed much further than previously but then I again got the same error with `abstractaudiooutput.h`.

Comment: These kind of problems are very time consuming. I would prefer to use Ubuntu 14 where Python3 is default.

Comment: @Netro Was putting it off but just upgraded. Thanks

Comment: OK, I installed Ubuntu 14.04, then set-up a virtuanenv and installed sip and pyqt4 into a virtualenv project. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010842/python-2-7-cannot-import-pyqt4 and http://problemssol.blogspot.com.au/2010/12/compile-and-install-pyqt4-for-python27.html were helpful for this. Now I can see /virten/lib/python3.4/site-packages/PyQt4  and running the virtenv in terminal I can import PyQt4. However in pyCharm->Project Interpreter->virtenv the PyQt4 package is not there - all other packages in the site-packages directory are there :-(

Comment: I found that although PyQt4 doesn't appear in the package list it is still recognised by the interpreter and all works now.

Comment: gr8. may be you can write your own awnser and accept it. :D

Answer (score 2):

One way to get pyQt4 working in Ubuntu:
Install Ubuntu14.04
Install virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper  eg [virtualenv](http://simononsoftware.com/virtualenv-tutorial-part-2/), [virtualenvwrapper](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html#python-versions)

Create a python3 virtualenv

```
mkvirtualenv testpy3 -p /usr/bin/python3.4
```

Now you should see (testpy3) at start of command line.
In this shell install sip (I got it working this way but may be better to download latest from riverbankcomputing as per pyQt below)

```
pip install sip
make
sudo make install
```

download pyQt from http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download
cd to the download folder, unpack the downloaded file. cd into the unpacked folder.
type

```
python configure-ng.py
make
sudo make install
```

Now test with

```
python
>>import PyQt4
```

This should work without errors.
Now in PyCharm 
file->settings->Project:Project Interpreter select the gear icon on topRHS->add local navigate to your testpy3 virtualenv (eg in /home/user/.virtualenvs). Through PyQt4 doesn't appear in the package list, PyCharm detected it and PyQt4 gui's are working for me.