# Error during installing PyQt4 for python 3 on ubuntu

Tags: python, pyqt

I use python 3.4

I have downloaded PyQt4 from http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download

When i configure PyQt4 by running the following command.

```
python configure-ng.py
```

I get the following error:

```
Querying qmake about your Qt installation...

qmake: could not exec '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/qmake': No such file or directory

Error: PyQt4 requires Qt v4.1.0 or later. Use the --qmake flag to specify the
correct version of qmake. If you are sure you are using Qt v4 then try the
configure.py script instead of this one.
```

Please can anyone help me with this..

Comment: `sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt4`

Answer (score 0):

I had difficulty getting to run but managed via documentation here: [PyQt4 install problems on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26956213/pyqt4-install-problems-on-ubuntu/27084675#27084675)