# How can I install PyQt and SIP for python 2.7 on Scientific Linux?

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, pyqt

I've asked a similar question [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/261822/python-plugins-dont-work-on-qgis-2-14-for-scientific-linux-7), with no response, but basically, how can I install PyQt and SIP for python 2.7 on Scientific Linux 7?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14997069/3182496) answer seemed to get me there, but I'm getting the error

```
error: ‘QPrinter::PrinterState’ is not a class or namespace
```

(And the same error for `QPaintEngine::Type`, `Qt::WindowFrameSelection`, `QStyle::SubControl`, `QValidator::State`.)

Any idea how to fix this, or find a better way to install PyQt?

Nearly all the other answers I've seen either relate to python 3 or Ubuntu, so I need a solution that works with python 2.7 on Scientific Linux (or RHEL/CentOS at least).

Comment: I was able to to find SL7 [pyqt4 rpms](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/37999561/dir/scientific_linux_7/com/PyQt4-4.10.1-13.el7.x86_64.rpm.html) and [sip rpms](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/38007572/dir/scientific_linux_7/com/sip-4.14.6-4.el7.x86_64.rpm.html) quite easily, so I don't quite see what the problem is. Why don't you just use your package manager to install whatever packages you require?

Comment: @ekhumoro Yep, I've done ```yum install qt qt-demos qt-designer qt4 qt4-designer qt-devel```, but when I open QGIS, it says 'cannot import module PyQt'.

Comment: Well, obviously those packages do not include **Py**Qt. I gave you links to the necessary packages - what more do you want?!

Comment: PS: is there no package manager application on SL7? It's a long time since I used a linux distro that used rpms (15 years ago maybe), but I seem to remember graphical package managers that had adequate search facilities. The first thing I would have done in a situation like this, was search for "pyqt" and "sip" and see what packages were available.